# Who was the first named character to die on screen in the Avatar (2005) animated canon?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

In the Avatar animated canon (The cartoon only, excluding all other media), who was the first named character to die on screen based on episode number, rather than their place in the time line.

So, a death the occurred in episode 2 would count as being before a death in a flashback in episode 3, even if the death in the flashback was something that happened earlier in the series timeline.

Comment: Tui, probably, in the episode at the end of Season 1. If memory serves, the culprit (Admiral Zhao) also dies shortly afterwards